# Unable to call an Api in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to call an API but whenever I call it I am getting **Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response** error and I don't know how to deal with it. Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to clarify what server technology you are using (language/framework/etc). [CORS](https://enable-cors.org/) needs to be enabled on the server.

Comment: i am using ionic 3.

Comment: Ionic is not a server technology, the issue is with the API (server) you are attempting to get data from. You need to provide more information regarding your API (language/framework/etc). CORS needs to be enabled on this API (server). It needs to be configured to be able to accept the HTTP requests you are making from your Ionic application.

Comment: Which language are you using in the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

Add this extension to your browser and enable it

Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *